# IntelliJ Enterprise Plugin Repository - Plugins' Metadata won't display

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have several proprietary IntelliJ plugins that I am hosting on an Enterprise Repository.  When I view them in IntelliJ's Repository Browser, the metadata does not display, besides the version.

(Note: None of the other plugins have metadata either)
[image: Browse Repositories View]

I am hosting these plugins at my.enterprise.repository.com/updatePlugins.xml, with the file

```
<plugins>
  <plugin 
    id="Plugin 1" 
    url="http://my.enterprise.repository.com/Plugin1.jar" 
    version="12.001" />
  <plugin 
    id="Plugin 2" 
    url="http://my.enterprise.repository.com/Plugin2.jar" 
    version="12.001"/>
  <plugin 
    id="Plugin 3" 
    url="http://my.enterprise.repository.com/Plugin3.jar" 
    version="12.001"/>
  <plugin 
    id="Plugin 4" 
    url="http://my.enterprise.repository.com/Plugin4.jar" 
    version="12.001"/>
  <plugin 
    id="Plugin 5" 
    url="http://my.enterprise.repository.com/Plugin5.jar" 
    version="12.001"/>
</plugins>
```

And the plugin.xml for Plugin 5 is

```
<idea-plugin version="2">
  <name>Plugin 5</name>
  <description>Is a cool plugin.</description>
  <version>12.001</version>
  <vendor>My Company</vendor>
  <idea-version since-build="8000"/>

  <application-components>
    <!-- Add your application components here -->
  </application-components>

  <project-components>
    <!-- Add your project components here -->
  </project-components>

  <extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">

    ...

  </extensions>
</idea-plugin>
```

Is the metadata specified in a different file?  Or is my plugin.xml file wrong?

Note: These plugins successfully download, install, and function.

Comment: These symptoms happen in both IntelliJ 11 Ultimate and IntelliJ 12 Community.  I haven't tested in any other version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known issue, the work is in progress. You can track the state here:

- [IDEA-88075](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-88075) Plugins in enterprise / custom plugin repository do not show plugin details